# How to create Custom payment module for thirdparty ipg in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, payment-gateway, payment

Anyone know how to create payment module for third party ipg. Is there any tutorial or step by step guide to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is no standard tutorial for this. Of course you need the developer docs. But if you haven't buildt one yet, you could always download a payment module from another PSP and have a look how they set it up. You can also use prestashops [module generator](https://validator.prestashop.com) as a start. Create an account. At the top of the page, you'll see the module generator link.

Added link to a [paymentexample](https://github.com/PrestaShop/paymentexample) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I found the solution. Simply we can use the [https://validator.prestashop.com] for generate payment module and then we can customize what we need. Really simple

Comment: That's exactly what @Mandy told you in her awnser. So mark her awnser as correct.